# Detect intersect with masked image (not rectangular)

Tags: swift, xcode

How to not get detected with **intersects func** when moving around masked image in UIImageView frame?

[explanation image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRiL5.png)

Code that I am using to detect collision:

```
movingPerson.frame.intersects(camera.frame)
```

Where movingPerson is just a regular UIImage that I am moving around with touchesmoved func and camera is a masked Image.
I've tried .bounds instead of .frame but it's not working.

Is there any easy way?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the "Very easy way" then [UIDynamicItem](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidynamicitem/1618493-collisionboundstype) and provide a path that bounds your image and let UIDynamicAnimator handle the collisions for you.  If you do not know how to get the path for your artwork (yours is pretty easy and you should be able to extract the Bezier coordinates automatically in Paintcode, by hand in Illustrator, or from a SVG file) you can use SpriteKit instead since it will actually generate the bounding polygon for your sprite automatically.

EDIT Sample (note I didn't want to write a whole app for this so I took an existing playground and just added the colliders.  the collision works, but the reset after collision doesn't):

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class ObstacleView: UIView {
    override var collisionBoundsType: UIDynamicItemCollisionBoundsType {
        return .path
    }

    override var collisionBoundingPath: UIBezierPath {
        return UIBezierPath(ovalIn: bounds)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        layer.cornerRadius = bounds.size.width / 2
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var dynamicAnimator: UIDynamicAnimator!
    var gravityBehavior: UIGravityBehavior!
    var pushBehavior: UIPushBehavior!
    var collisionBehavior: UICollisionBehavior!
    lazy var player: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = ""
        label.sizeToFit()
        label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(label)
        return label
    }()
    var isPanning = false
    var anchor: CGPoint = .zero
    let maxDistance = CGFloat(100)
    lazy var obstacles: [UIView] = {
        return (0..<2).map { index in
            let view = ObstacleView(frame: CGRect(x:100 + CGFloat(index)*200,y:200, width: 40, height: 40))
            view.backgroundColor = .blue
            view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            self.view.addSubview(view)
            return view
        }
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        dynamicAnimator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: view)
        dynamicAnimator.delegate = self
        gravityBehavior = UIGravityBehavior(items: [player])
        let panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(pan))
        _ = obstacles
        view.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        anchor = view.center
        player.center = anchor
    }

    @objc private func pan(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        switch recognizer.state {
        case .began:
            guard player.bounds.contains(recognizer.location(in: player)) else {
                isPanning = false
                return
            }
            isPanning = true
        case .changed:
            guard isPanning else {
                return
            }
            player.center = recognizer.location(in: view)
            let dx = player.center.x - anchor.x
            let dy = player.center.y - anchor.y
            let distance = CGFloat(hypotf(Float(dx), Float(dy)))
            if distance > maxDistance {
                player.center.x = anchor.x + dx / distance * maxDistance
                player.center.y = anchor.y + dy / distance * maxDistance
            }
        case .ended:
            guard isPanning else {
                return
            }
            isPanning = false
            let dx = player.center.x - anchor.x
            let dy = player.center.y - anchor.y
            let distance = CGFloat(hypotf(Float(dx), Float(dy)))
            guard distance > 10 else {
                player.center = anchor
                return
            }
            if pushBehavior != nil {
                dynamicAnimator.removeBehavior(pushBehavior)
            }
            pushBehavior = UIPushBehavior(items: [player], mode: .instantaneous)
            pushBehavior.pushDirection = CGVector(dx: -dx, dy: -dy)
            pushBehavior.magnitude = distance / maxDistance * 0.75
            dynamicAnimator.addBehavior(pushBehavior)
            dynamicAnimator.addBehavior(gravityBehavior)
            collisionBehavior = UICollisionBehavior(items: [player] + obstacles)
            collisionBehavior.translatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary = true
            collisionBehavior.collisionDelegate = self
            dynamicAnimator.addBehavior(collisionBehavior)
        case .cancelled:
            isPanning = false
            player.center = anchor
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController: UIDynamicAnimatorDelegate {
    func dynamicAnimatorDidPause(_ animator: UIDynamicAnimator) {
        dynamicAnimator.removeAllBehaviors()
        player.center = anchor
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollisionBehaviorDelegate {
    func collisionBehavior(_ behavior: UICollisionBehavior, beganContactFor item1: UIDynamicItem, with item2: UIDynamicItem, at p: CGPoint) {
        print("contact")
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ViewController()
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

Comment: Seems like the way to go. Let's say, I have a label which shows text "detected" when collision happens. Can you help me with some code? I will manage somehow Bezier path, but just need to see example code how to put it all together. Thanks in advance!

Comment: See edited answer.  In particular you want to look at `ObstacleView` for how to setup your custom collision path.